# How to send control char using strict mode in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";
var debug = function( m ) { 
    console.log('   \033[32mdebug -\033[39m:' + m ); 
}
```

The \033 is not going to fly with the strict mode any way around that beside taking off the strict mode?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `\033`?

Comment: @AvengerMojo: What do you use to run the JavaScript? node?

Comment: @KooiInc: \033 is escape. http://linux.die.net/man/4/console_codes `\033[32m` changes the foreground color. http://www.bashguru.com/2010/01/shell-colors-colorizing-shell-scripts.html

Comment: I'm sure there is a package which handles color codes nicely for you. Don't do it on your own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\u001b` instead. `\0...` is an octal escape sequence which your JavaScript environment might not support.

Comment: thanks the unicode char table help http://etutorials.org/Programming/actionscript/Appendix+A.+Unicode+Escape+Sequences+for+Latin+1+Characters/

Comment: this is especially useful for Coffeescript which runs in strict mode

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to use the [colorette](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colorette) package. Once you install the package with:
`yarn add colorette`
then you can do something like:

```
const { red, blue, bold } = require("colorette");
console.log(bold(blue("Engage!")));
```

Nice and simple.

Comment: This will only work for colours though, if you want to use ANSI codes for things like erasing lines then `colorette` can't help.