# Are there different types of escape sequences?

Tags: javascript, unicode, escaping, html-escape-characters

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170631/2404470)

The answer listed two escape sequences:

`\033` - [AaronDigulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla) referred this as **octal** type of escape sequence.

- What type of escape sequence the other one `\u001b` is?
- Are there different types of escape sequences? If yes are they listed somewhere?

Comment: They're all listed in the Javascript/Ecmascript specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those starting with '\u' are in [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Yes, there are some escape types. Off the top of my head, you can also use octal `\0...` and hexadecimal `\0x...`.

[List](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) of javascript escapes types:

- Single character escape sequences
- Octal escape sequences
- Hexadecimal escape sequences
- Unicode escape sequences
- ECMAScript 6: Unicode code point escapes
- Control escape sequences

Comment: There are also lettered escape sequences like `\n` for newline, `\t` for tab, etc.